# Market price Pt at any time

Tags: economics

So I have this question and answer to it which one part i'm stuck understanding, here's the question.

Given demand & supply functions as  = 86 − 0.8  and  = −10 + 0.2 −1
Find:

a) the market price 
in any time.

Here's the answer which I understand:

Equating demand and supply, we will have:

86 − 0.8  = −10 + 0.2 −1 ⟹ −0.8  = 0.2 −1 − 96

Or

= −.  t-1 +

Using the iterative method, we have:

= 1 ⟹ 1 = (−. ) o +

= 2 ⟹ 2 = (−0.25)1 + 120 = −0.25(−0.25 o + 120) + 120

= 2 ⟹ 2 = (−. )^2.o + ( − . )

= 3 ⟹ 3 = (−. )^3.o + ( − .  + (. )^2)

=  ⟹  = (−. )^t.o + ( − .  + ⋯ + (−)^(t-1) .^(t-1))

and then here comes the part which I'm stuck understanding:

We can re-write this as:
 = (o −(/( + . ))) (−. )^t +/(1+0.25)

How do we derive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll clear up the notation a little bit. We have a recursive equation
$$
P_t = a+qP_{t-1}
$$
where $a$ and $q$ are constants. In your case, $a>0$ and $q<0$. If we assume that we know $P_0$ (the initial value of $P$), then we can calculate
$$
P_1 = a+qP_{0}
$$
and of course
$$
P_2 = a+qP_{1} = a+q(a+qP_{0}) = a + qa + q^2 P_0 = a(1+q) + q^2 P_0
$$
Going further, we have
$$
P_3 = a(1+q+q^2) + q^3 P_0
$$
$$
P_3 = a(1+q+q^2+q^3) + q^4 P_0
$$
We can see a pattern forming. The expression in the parenthesis is a geometric sum. Let's denote
$$
S(n) = 1 +q + q^2 + \ldots + q^n \tag{1}
$$
then, multiplying both sides by $q$, we get
$$
qS(n) = q +q^2 + q^3 + \ldots + q^n + q^{n+1} \tag{2}
$$
Let's subtract equation ($2$) from equation ($1$). The result is
$$
S(n)-qS(n) = 1-q^{n+1}
$$
from which we can solve $S(n) = \frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$.

Returning to the original question, we can easily see that the answer is
$$
P_n = a\frac{1-q^{n}}{1-q} + q^n P_0
$$

Comment: Thanks! I rewrote it the way you did and derived it.