# Express the accumulated amount in the bank as an explicit formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

Suppose I earn 500 dollars every month. If I deposit my monthly income fully into the bank, the bank pays interest of 0.25 % per month on the accumulated amount from the previous month.

For example:
Assuming n=months,

January, n=1, the accumulated amount would be $500

February, n=2, the accumulated amount would be $500 * 1.0025 + $500 = $1001.25

How do I find the explicit formula for the accumulated amount?

Comment: Oh... I see. You're talkin' about compound interest ?

Comment: This is a typical linear recurrence of the form$$a_{n+1}=1.0025a_n+500,\quad a_1=500$$which has the solution$$a_n=200000(1.0025^n-1)$$

Comment: Oho..... something I can't answer. Thanks for letting me know...

Comment: This is a very widely discussed math problem. For example, here's essentially the same problem, with the solution :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164490/market-price-pt-at-any-time/3164532#3164532